# class constructor after inheritance

Tags: flutter

i'm new to flutter i can't get the constructor to work which is in comment,
but the other constructor works, why? thank you

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:photo_view/photo_view.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: ImageEditor()
       // child: PhotoView(imageProvider: AssetImage("Assets/img/carte.png"),)
    );
  }
}


class ImageEditor extends PhotoView {
  // ignore: missing_required_param
  ImageEditor():super(imageProvider: AssetImage("Assets/img/carte.png"),){
    init();
  }
  //ImageEditor(){
  // super(imageProvider: AssetImage("Assets/img/carte.png"),);
  // init()
  // }
  void init(){
    if(imageProvider!=null) {
      print("il y a peut etre moyen de dessiner sur l'image");}
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not valid syntax

Answer (score 0):

This is what you call a **super constructor**.

```
ImageEditor():super(imageProvider: AssetImage("Assets/img/carte.png")){
  init();
}
```

Normally, a subclass can inherit all the variables and function from the parent class(using the **extends**) keyword, but you cannot access its constructor.
Using the : super() argument, you can however call the constructor from the parent class. You can only do it that way, that is simply the syntax.

Example:

```
class Class1 {
  Class1(String name) {
    print("Hello $name");
  }
}

class Class2 extends Class1 {
  Class2() : super("Tom") { //the name from above
    print("Hello World");
  }
}

void main() {
  Class2 test = new Class2();
}
```

The output would be(in that order):

```
Hello Tom
Hello World
```

Comment: thank you this must be part of the difference with java